# Document Viewer using JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee

Want to develop a web application that displays various document formats (includes doc,docx,pdf,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx..etc).That is according to user selection it want to view selected file in the webpage.

Help me to find a solution to display various file formats in JSP.
Is there any open source viewer for separate file  formats that supports JSP.

Comment: You need a Flash plugin to display proprietary file formats in the browser like that. This is not something you can do in ANY serverside language (JSP, PHP, etc.) without using Flash on the frontend.